# How to disable client-initiated renegotiation in Postfix?

Tags: linux, ssl, security, email, postfix

How to disable client-initiated renegotiation in Postfix?

Answer (score 4):

In console:

```
nano etc/postfix/main.cf
```

Find & edit - or add this line:

```
tls_ssl_options = NO_RENEGOTIATION
```

The value of [the `tls_ssl_options`  configuration parameter](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#tls_ssl_options) is a *white-space or comma separated list of named options*, with an alternate syntax provided for (only in exceptional circumstances recommendable) directly specifying OpenSSL-supported options not (yet) named at Postfix compile time.

Comment: Do you know how to do it in postfix 2.10 ?

Comment: Because TLS 1.3 forbids renegotiation, this is only needed when allowing legacy TLS (1.2 or prior) in the first place.